# Полная загрузка и буферизация видео перед показом

Tags: javascript, видео

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт, который должен срабатывать только после полной загрузки конкретного видео. Как я не пытался, но у меня почему-то загрузка идет частичная. Как сделать так, к примеру вывести alert(1), только после того, как видео было полностью загружено/пробуферизовано. Я в тупике.

Answer (score 1):

Осуществить можно вот так. Но сама буферизация видео не идёт. Это уже от браузера зависит, когда он начнёт и закончит буферизацию

```js
$(function() {
  $('#video')[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    var e = this;
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      if(e.duration == e.buffered.end(0)){
        console.log('Загрузилось :)');
        clearInterval(int);
      };
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
video {width:400px;height: 250px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Сидел 2 часа пытался найти, что бы буферизация изначально шла полностью, но без успешно :(

Comment: Истинный фанатизм не знает пределов, да? :)

Comment: @Other, та вообще )